# Writing Images to s3fs.S3FileSystem after preprocessing image

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, python-s3fs

Am currently accessing a s3 bucket from my school system. 
To connect, I used the following:

```
import s3fs
from skimage import exposure
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(client_kwargs={'endpoint_url': 'XXX'},
                       key='XXX',
                       secret='XXX')
```

I can retrieve an image from the s3 bucket as defined above and preprocess them using

```
infile = s3.open('test.jpg',"rb")
image = Image.open(infile)
img = np.asarray(image) #numpy.ndarray
img_eq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img,clip_limit=0.03) #CLAHE
image_eq = Image.fromarray((img_eq * 255).astype(np.uint8)) #Convert back to image
```

To save the resulting image <image_eq> locally, would just be

```
image_eq.save("hello.jpg")
```

However, how do I save/write the resulting image into the s3fs filesystem instead?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Simone unfortunately no. I have since moved on from this issue. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`save` in Pillow accepts a file too. You could do:

```
 image_eq.save(fs.open('s3://bucket/file.png', 'wb'), 'PNG')
```

You have to write a binary file. I think it works best by enforcing the file type, e.g. in this case PNG.